# What is the best constant C such that (a+b)^t <= C(a^t+b^t)?

Tags: inequality

Let t in (0,1). What is the best constant C such that, for all a,b > 0, (a+b)^t <= C(a^t+b^t) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like OP wants his homework done for him

Comment: Not really, it's just by curiosity because the answer is easy if t is an integer. I'm in second year of master in mathematics (sorry for my english...). I know that C=2^(t-1) is the best constant for t >= 1. But for t < 1... I'm stucked ! Can you help me please ? It's my first question on Stak overflow.